# Android Runtime Error using Scala and libGDX with Gradle

Tags: android, scala, gradle, libgdx

I want to build android apk in my libGdx project but I got this error shows up
My other projects with libgdx and scala works well.

I have it on this part of the code:

```
        tempArray = stage.getActors.items.array.filter(_ != null).filter(_.getName == "ball1")
```

```
W/com.scala.gdx: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/invoke/VarHandle;->releaseFence()V (blacklist, reflection, denied)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 456
    Process: com.scala.gdx, PID: 8618
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
      ...
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1557)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1272)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.VarHandle.releaseFence []
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2072)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2050)
        at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.findStatic(MethodHandles.java:782)
       ...
        at a.a.a.p.a.l.onSurfaceChanged(:310) 
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1557) 
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1272)
```

Comment: Can you provide more info regarding config files, and a sample of how you are using the lib. That can help the community to have more context and to provide a proper answer